# Define header ones and use it across multiple RDLC

Tags: header, rdlc

Does anyone know is it possible define header ones and use it across multiple RDLC?

Comment: your question needs more context.

Comment: I have many RDLC files with exact the same header. If there is a need of some changes in header, I must make changes in many RDLC files. So I would like to have only one header file, and make some kind of include in all other RDLC files. Is that possible?